# Flutter webview_flutter: Not able to detect platform with java-script code

Tags: javascript, html, css, flutter

I am using webview_flutter to show a web page. I am using the below code to detect the platform, like is it android or ios. My below code is not working.
Flutter webview - https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter
I have added the below class in body.

```
class - view-withKeyboard


function applyAfterResize() {
            console.log(getMobileOperatingSystem());
            if (getMobileOperatingSystem() == 'ios') {
                if (originalPotion !== false) {
                    var wasWithKeyboard = $('body').hasClass('view-withKeyboard');
                    var nowWithKeyboard = false;
                        var diff = Math.abs(originalPotion - ($(window).width() + $(window).height()));
                        if (diff > 100) nowWithKeyboard = true;
                    $('body').toggleClass('view-withKeyboard', nowWithKeyboard);
                    if (wasWithKeyboard != nowWithKeyboard) {
                        //onKeyboardOnOff(nowWithKeyboard);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $(document).on('focus blur', '.white-div input[type=text]', function(e){
            //alert('here');
            if (getMobileOperatingSystem() == 'ios') {
              var $obj = $(this);
              var nowWithKeyboard = (e.type == 'focusin');
              $('body').toggleClass('view-withKeyboard', nowWithKeyboard);
              onKeyboardOnOff(nowWithKeyboard);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you show us the WebView widget on how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Enable JavascriptMOde first and use evaluateJavascript

```
WebView(
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    initialUrl: '',
    onWebViewCreated:
        (WebViewController webViewController) async {
      webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
          "javascript:(function() { " +
              "console.log('Test Test Test');" +
              "})()");
    },
  ),
```